# What does x<-xs in Haskell mean?

Tags: haskell

In one of my courses I came across this:

```
numbers xs = [x | x<−xs , even x]
```

I understand that it takes a list of numbers and creates another list formed only with the even numbers from the original list. How exactly is it doing this? What does `x<-xs` mean?

Comment: in this case, it means "take each element of the list `xs` and substitute `x` for each such element in sequence". More generally, in a monadic context (a do block), it means name binding to the return value of the monadic action.

Comment: Read about [list comprehension](https://wiki.haskell.org/List_comprehension).

Answer (score 7):

This is a [list comprehension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension) where the notation is designed to be similar to [set builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation#Convention_of_annotating_the_variable_domain_on_the_left_of_the_.27such_that.27) with the token `<-` corresponding to the stylized lower case Greek epsilon which is the standard symbol for set membership. When I read list comprehensions I tend to read `<-` as "drawn from", so I would parse `[x | x<−xs , even x]` as "the list of all x  such that x is drawn from xs and x is even" (`,` corresponds to `and` and is used to add conditions beyond mere membership in the list which is being drawn from).

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers stated this a list comprehension notation, which means a way of defining a list in terms of another list. If you specify some predicates in the part after a `|`, only elements satisfying these predicates will be taken, for example `[x | x <- xs, even x]` is a list of all those elements `x` taken from the list `xs` that are even (meet the condition `even x`). There can be more than one predicate:

```
[x | x <- xs, even x, x > 10]
```

You can also apply transformations to the drawn elements, including changing the list type:

```
λ> [x*2 | x <- [1 .. 20], even x, x > 10]
[24,28,32,36,40]
```

or:

```
λ> [show x | x <- [1 .. 20], even x, x > 10]
["12","14","16","18","20"]
```